# phpBB and mySQL "Could not connect to the database..."

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb

I am trying to set up a phpBB forum on a locally hosted webpage. It being done in an openSUSE Linux OS.

I have installed MariaDB (MySQL), and created a new database named `new_database` using the command `CREATE DATABASE new_database;`, along with a user named `user` with the command `CREATE USER 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`. I also changed the root password to `password`, just for testing purposes.

When I enter this info into the phpBB installation database settings screen, I get the error

> Could not connect to the database, see error message below.
>
> Access denied for user 'new_user'@'localhost' to database 'new_database'.

I am using `localhost` for the DSN. Any ideas? From everything I've found online it should be working...

Answer (score 2):

After you create the user you have to **Grant Privileges**, this is how you do it.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON new_database.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

Do not forget to flush.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Common Privileges

```
ALL PRIVILEGES- all access
CREATE- allows them to create new tables or databases
DROP- allows them to them to delete tables or databases
DELETE- allows them to delete rows from tables
INSERT- allows them to insert rows into tables
SELECT- allows them to use the Select command to read through databases
UPDATE- allow them to update table rows
GRANT OPTION- allows them to grant or remove other users' privileges
```

You can specify the database and table.

```
new_database.* (Specific Database, all tables)
new_database.table (Specific Database, specific table)
*.* (all databases, al tables)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a phpBB install and solved the problem by accessing the database through phpMyAdmin and noticing on the splash page it said "User: pits@localhost", which was different from the user (pits_bull) I had created and attached to the database and was trying to connect with.

I tried it with just "pits" and it worked. Not sure whether there is a security issue with that though, or why it worked, but it IS working!